# jqGrid alternate for Mobile apps

Tags: javascript, mobile, jqgrid, rhomobile, rhodes

Is there any thing similar to jqGrid available for Mobile applications ?
Could someone please suggest a javascript plugin that I can use with RhoMobile platform ?

Answer (score 1):

jqgrid works without issues in Mobile devices. You should use it

Answer (score 0):

Rhodes (RhoMobile's client application framework) applications are built in Ruby (for your "server-side" business logic) and HTML (for your views.)  The applications are rendered in a native web-view on the device.  Therefore, the application you write is limited only by the web-view of the device that it is running on.